# Regex to allow specials chars

Tags: regex

I have a classic regex like that ([a-z]+) who allow only lowercase chars and I want to allow this chars "-"

How to ?

I already looked on google but I only found tutorial in english which isn't my first language and its very difficulte to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just simply include it in the brackets:

```
([a-z-]+)
```

Answer (score 1):

If `-` may have a meaning, then write `\-`, else write simply `-` :

To allow a,b and - :

`[ab-]` or `[a\-b]` or `[-ab]`

Answer (score 0):

Include `-` in your character class:

```
[-a-z]+
```